# ONCLICK: Verify value on select if nothing put others or value with asterisk

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have a button that pass the value of input box to my select.** The problem is when the value of my input box are didn't have in my select it show empty. **But I want to show OTHERS if it's empty or shows the given value and put asterisk, e.g. POTATO* .**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="fruitname" id="fruitname" placeholder="Fruit Name"></input>
<button name="findfruit" id="findfruit" onclick="findfruit()">Find Fruit in Select</button> 
<select name="fruitcontainer" id="fruitcontainer">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Coconut">Coconut</option>
    <option value="Durian">Durian</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findfruit(){
        document.getElementById('fruitcontainer').value = document.getElementById('fruitname').value;   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So if you type in a value that the select does not have you want the input to have the value typed + *?

Comment: Yeah you've got it.@trevster344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if the text input one of the possible values of the `<select>`.

```js
function findfruit() {
  var value = document.getElementById('fruitname').value;
  if (value == '') {
    value = "Others";
  } else if (!document.querySelector("#fruitcontainer option[value='" + value + "']")) {
    value += '*';
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.value = value;
    newOption.textContent = value;
    document.getElementById('fruitcontainer').appendChild(newOption);
  }
  document.getElementById('fruitcontainer').value = value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fruitname" id="fruitname" placeholder="Fruit Name"></input>
<button name="findfruit" id="findfruit" onclick="findfruit()">Find Fruit in Select</button>
<select name="fruitcontainer" id="fruitcontainer">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Coconut">Coconut</option>
    <option value="Durian">Durian</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but almost their sir @Barmar. But I need that value with asterisk in the select not in the input box sir.

Comment: So you want to add a new option to the select?

Comment: Yes sir @Barmar for example if I put POTATO in the input box the value of select should be POTATO*.

Comment: Updated the answer.